# Luntbuild for .net

Tags: .net, luntbuild

Is it possible to use Luntbuild to build .net projects?

Comment: Probably, with a lot of work. Why would you want to, as .NET has a number of good build systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching my head for one day, I found out that it can also be used for .NET. 
First you have to create a script file ( NAnt or msbuild or whatever) to build the project.
You just have to provide the path of the batch file which runs the script.